# Append newline to a Base64 encoded string.

Tags: java, apache, base64, apache-commons

```
byte[] serObj = getBytesFromFile(file);
final byte[] CLRF = { '\r', '\n' };
Base64 encoded = new Base64 (72,CLRF);
System.out.println(encoded.encodeBase64String(serObj));
```

I am having problems formatting the output, which currently displays as a single line, and not according to the args in constructor. It is supposed to be a line with 72 chars and followed by CLRF and the next line. Can someone point out what's wrong with the code? Also, how could I manually append/add a newline char within a String? I tried using a char counter, but I am stuck on how to add the \n once the counter reaches the 72nd char.

```
public static int count(Reader in) throws IOException {
char[] buffer = new char[4096];
int count = 0;
int len;
while((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    count += len;
}
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`encodeBase64String(byte[])`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String%28byte%5B%5D%29) method you are calling is a `static` method, so the `Base64` instance that you created is not being used by the method call.

You should be using the [`encodeToString(byte[])`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeToString%28byte%5B%5D%29) method, which is an instance method.